# Angular4: Como recuperar valores no Response Headers

Tags: angular, http-headers

Tenho um WebService que retorna um arquivo PDF (byte[]). Estou retornando o nome do arquivo no Header da resposta.

No Chrome eu consigo ver os valores de 'Response Headers' e vejo que todos os headers estão lá, inclusive o nome do arquivo. Porém, quando tento recuperar esses valores no Angular, eu não consigo, pois no headers vem apenas o "Content-Type:application/pdf".

```
getPdf(url: string){

    this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'arraybuffer', observe:'response'})
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data.headers.get('filename')); // Imprime: null
            console.log(data.headers.keys()); // Imprime: ["Content-Type"]
            this.downloadFile(data.body);
    });
  }
```

Response Headers exibido no navegador:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Request-Width, Content-Type, Accept, authCode
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=arquivo.pdf
Content-Type:application/pdf
Date:Mon, 26 Nov 2018 14:23:37 GMT
filename:arquivo.pdf
Server:JBoss-EAP/7
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:Undertow/1
```

Alguém sabe o que está errado? Como faço para recuperar esse valor?

Comment: Tenta assim: `data.headers.get('Content-Disposition').split(';')[1].trim().split('=')[1]` se funcionar te explico. Não tenho como testar!

Comment: Não funciona assim pois ele só está recebendo o 'Content-Type' nos headers.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o problema. No retorno do meu serviço, preciso definir os Headers que eu quero expostos com o valor 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers'. Se não definir isso o Angular ignora os valores passados.

Por exemplo, meu webservice em java ficou:

```
protected Response buildFile(Status status, byte[] file, String nomeArquivo) {
        return Response.status(status)
                .entity(file)
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
                .header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition, filename")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
                .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+ nomeArquivo)
                .header("filename", nomeArquivo)
                .build();
    }
```

Mais informações sobre:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044299/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-file-downloaded-with-angular5

Comment: Depois dessa sua alteração o código que mostrei não funcionou?

Comment: Não. Respondi seu comentário lá.